# What AMF Servers Support Remote Shared Objects?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, amf, weborb, zend-amf

Greetings. I'm planning on building a Flex based multiplayer game, and I'm researching what will be required for the server end. I have PHP experience, so I started looking at ZendAMF.

Now in this game, I'll need the concept of rooms, and real time updates to clients in those rooms, so it looks like I'll be using remote shared objects (correct, yes?). I'm not seeing where ZendAMF can support this.

So I found this page: http://arunbluebrain.wordpress.com/2009/03/04/flex-frameworks-httpcorlanorg/

It seems to indicate that ZendAMF isn't going to do what I want.  WebORB for PHP seems to be the only PHP based solution that does messaging, but on that page it doesn't mention "real-time" next to it like the Java based ones below it do.

What should I be looking at for the server piece with my requirements?  Do I need to make the jump to something like BlazeDS and try to pick up a bit of Java knowledge?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both ZendAmf and weborb use http long pulling. Think of it as pinging to check for updates. If you really need TRUE realtime push notification then PHP will not be your answer due to it not having threads or long running processes. WebOrb has several servers in other languages along with BlazeDS, RubyAMF, PyAmf, and of course LCDS from adobe that allows for true messaging.

Comment: Are BlazeDS and LCDS the only servers that support Shared Objects?  I'm not seeing that RubyAMF supports this.  Seems like it's in the same position as PHP

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly reccommed flash media server if you have the cash.
I've had good expereince with it in the past

Answer (score 0):

I think you already know the answer, but for other people looking into this as well:

All *AMF solutions use HTTP as transfer protocol and can't have permanent connection. AMF is sent encoded through HTTP and then it's closed.

When you want to use "real" real-time (RTMP,RTMPT), you have choices like:
opensource: Red5 (Java), BlazeDS (Java), FluorineFX (.NET)
commercial: Wowza Media Server (Java), WebORB (.NET and Java)

Comment: For commercial servers, I think you forgot Flash Media Server